# Failed prop type issue

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following structure:

[image]

and a TodoList component as follow:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Todo from './Todo'

const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map( (todo, i) => (
      <Todo key={i} {...todo} onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)} />
    ))}
  </ul>
)

TodoList.propTypes = {
  todos: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired
  ).isRequired,
  onTodoClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default TodoList
```

I am getting the following error:

[image]

this is my index in the reducers folder:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
  ADD_TODO,
  TOGGLE_TODO,
  SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER,
  VisibilityFilters
} from '../actions/index'
const { SHOW_ALL } = VisibilityFilters

function visibilityFilter(state = SHOW_ALL, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return action.filter
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      return state.map((todo, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: !todo.completed
          })
        }
        return todo
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const todoApp = combineReducers({
  visibilityFilter,
  todos
})

export default todoApp
```

The onTodoClick doesn't fire either in TodoList and it's defined here:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleTodo } from '../actions/index'
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList'

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
    default:
      return todos
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: id => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)

export default VisibleTodoList
```

Comment: what is the initial value of `todos` ? in parent component

Comment: As you see in the error, the ID for each TODO is requiere, the error shown because the ID attribute does not exists.

Comment: You should remove isRequired attribute from `PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired` since in an empty array the object is undefined